# no match for ‘operator=’ when std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I see a code using exactly this, but that code works and mine not, any idea why?

PD: im trying to implement this [commit](https://github.com/litecoincash-project/litecoincash/commit/727ef16c53c32b710d3e23091ac165dffa8f2da4#diff-97c3a52bc5fad452d82670a7fd291800bae20c7bc35bb82686c2c0a4ea7b5b98R3135). See that the code is exactly the same

```cpp
for(const auto& tx : block.vtx)
    if (txHash == tx->GetHash()) {
        txNew = tx;
        foundAtOut = *pindex;
        return true;
    }
```

```
main.cpp:2471:25: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘CTransactionRef’ {aka ‘std::shared_ptr<const CTransaction>’} and ‘const CTransaction’)
             txNew = tx;
```

Comment: `shared_ptr::operator=` expects to be assigned either a raw pointer, another `shared_ptr`, or a `unique_ptr`. `txNew` is a `shared_ptr`  but `tx` is none of those things that are compatible with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully: you are trying to assign an object of type `const CTransaction` to a shared pointer of type `std::shared_ptr<const CTransaction>`. But you can't do that using `operator=`, because its argument should be a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, as described at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D).

Depending on your actual code, I think, you can create a new `shared_ptr` for the `const CTransaction` object and then assign to it.

Comment: this is my actual typedef: typedef std::shared_ptr<const CTransaction> CTransactionRef;

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani that much is obvious from the error message. What is not obvious is what `block.vtx` is, and why you expect its elements to be assignment compatible with `CTransactionRef`

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani `tx` is not a `const CTransaction*`, it's a `const CTransaction` - and you would need `txNew.reset(tx)` if `tx` had been a pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but i use & on const auto

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani If this answer doesn't answer your question, make your question clearer by showing the necessary code. Make a [mre].

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani that use of `&` makes `tx` be a **reference**, not a **pointer**. Which means `block.vtx` must be a `CTransaction` object, not a `CTransaction*` pointer, in order to bind the reference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo im trying to implement this commit : https://github.com/litecoincash-project/litecoincash/commit/727ef16c53c32b710d3e23091ac165dffa8f2da4#diff-97c3a52bc5fad452d82670a7fd291800bae20c7bc35bb82686c2c0a4ea7b5b98R3135 . The code is the same as mine, but idk why that code works and mine not.

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani If you make a [mre] someone will tell you why it doesn't work. A commit in some external repo is not a [mre] - and that commit probably works so it does not help us in understanding how _your_ code looks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i cant made it reproducible, this is the code of Bitcoin, you would need do 10 thousand steps to made it even run. Check the github link above please

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani No, you could make an example in 5-10 lines of code to replicate your problem. [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Kr3GMn)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, that helpme a lot, but a last question, i need change the type of vtx on the class of block or i should change the const auto?

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani in the original code, `block.vtx` is a `std::vector<CTransactionRef>`, thus `tx` is deduced as `const CTransactionRef&` when the `vector` is enumerated by the loop. Thus `tx` can be assigned to another `CTransactionRef`, in this case `txNew`. Clearly that is not the case in your code. It is your job to figure out why that is. Your variables are not the types you are expecting.